# Attaching data to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined a list of components `components` as follows.

```
components = Immutable.fromJS(['string', 'number', 'object', array]).filter (type) =>
  type isnt @props.object.get('type')
.map (type) =>
  'to ' + type
.map (typeString) =>
  <a href='#' onClick={@handleClick}>{typeString}</a>
```

However I would like to *attach* some information to my created components for later access during callback (`@handleClick`). Is there a way to do this in ReactJS?

Note: A workaround for this is to create a new custom component, and pass the data I need as props, and send this props back during the callback.

Comment: What do you mean by attach? And what do you want to attach?

Comment: I want to attach the data ``type`` that I had during creation time and access it during the callback through other means such as through the SyntheticEvent or direct querying from event source.

Comment: Why don't you just add a `data-` attribute to the `<a>` tag?

Comment: use `handleClick.bind(this, type)`